# Allign mouse-events opencv with Django

Tags: python, django, opencv

I am working on a project now where I am using python code to draw some stuff on videos using opencv. My idea is to incoorporate this in a django application. My question is whether it is possible to integrate the mousevents,which are necessary for the drawing part, as well. Hope that someone can help me out.

Comment: Please try something first and then post your question.

Comment: if you mean to catch mouse event in django web page then maybe better use `JavaScript` and `<canvas>` in `HTML` for catching and drawing. Eventually you will have to use `JavaScript` with `<canvas>` to catch mouse event, and `JavaScript` with `AJAX` to send mouse position to server which will use OpenCV for drawing, and `JavaScript` with `AJAX` to get image with result and display it on page. So it will be hard work to write it.

Comment: But how can I let the mousecallback function work?